# ECIES with AES-GCM

Tags: gcm, ecies

The Elliptic Curve Integrated Encryption Scheme (ECIES) describes how to derive a "temporal" key, encrypt a message (eg. using AES) and creating a MAC.

However, from my understanding using AES in GCM mode makes using an additional MAC obsolete. So, is it then safe to skip the MAC calculation step in ECIES when using AES-GCM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's perfectly safe; GCM provides both the confidentially and integrity guarantees that ECIES requires.

Just a few notes:

- It doesn't matter what nonce you use; in fact, you can shrink the ciphertext a few bytes by making it implicit (as you'll use this GCM key only once)
- The AAD information you give GCM can either be empty, or optionally include a shared secret ($S_2$ on the Wikipedia article)

Comment: Can you elaborate on why the nonce could be fixed, eg: all 1's? Is this because the ephemeral is never used twice?

Comment: @JonathanS.Fisher: it is precisely because you never use the same GCM key twice, which is true if you never use the same ECIES ephemeral twice.

Comment: @poncho If there is, could you give a quotable source? That would be very helpful.

Comment: @jvdh: I'm not sure what source you want, but first, what are you asking about?  That ECIES doesn't repeat keys if you don't reuse the same ephemeral? Or, if GCM is safe to use with fixed nonces if you never repeat keys?

Comment: That you don't need a MAC and KDF when using ECIES with AES in GCM mode

Comment: @jvdh: well, you do need a KDF (that's part of the definition of ECIES); as for a MAC, GCM already provides that functionality.